# How to ignore vectors of zeros (i.e. paddings) in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, word-embeddings

I'm implementing a `LSTM` model with Keras. My dataset is composed by words and each word is an 837 long vector. I grouped the words in groups of 20 and to do this I padded them: initially I had groups of words of variable length and the maximum group length that I found was 20, this is why I padded all groups to 20.

For example, a group of 5 words is:

```
[[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837]]
```

where `xi` is the i-th feature of the vector.

To pad this group to a length of 20, I added 15 vectors composed by 837 feature with value equal to zeros:

```
[[0.......0],
............
............
[0........0]]
```

So, at the end, my group is of the form:

```
[[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[x1,x2....x837],
[0...........0],
..............
..............
[0...........0]]
```

How could I ignore the vectors of zeros during training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Masking` layer (with mask value of zero) before `LSTM` layer in order to ignore all timesteps with only zeros (i.e. zeros vector). You can find more information about this layer on its [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking). Here is an example from documentation which uses `Masking` layer:

> Consider a Numpy data array `x` of shape `(samples, timesteps, features)`,
>   to be fed to an `LSTM` layer. You want to mask sample #0 at timestep #3,
>   and sample #2 at timestep #5, because you lack features for these
>   sample timesteps. You can do:
>
> - set `x[0, 3, :] = 0.` and `x[2, 5, :] = 0.`
> - insert a `Masking` layer with `mask_value=0.` before the `LSTM` layer:
>
>   ```
>   model = Sequential()
>   model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
>   model.add(LSTM(32))
>   ```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.